# Django pass family in template inside for cycle

Tags: python, django, django-views

In a simple view I pass a family in template like this:

```
def page(request):
    family= Author.objects.all()
    return render(request, "myapp/page.html", {'family':family})
```

and I render in template like this:

```
{% for item in family %}
   {{ item.pk }}
{% endfor %}
```

But, if I put my family inside a for cycle; for example:

```
def page(request):
    family = []
    for i in range(5):
        family= Author.objects.filter(name='John')[i]
    return render(request, "myapp/page.html", {'family':family})
```

it not render anything in template...

Any idea?

EDIT 1

I have more users in my app, every user has different blog and every blog has different post...
So when user is logged i need to show his blog and for every blog show last 5 post.
I do:

```
@login_required
def page(request):
    user = request.user.id
    numblog = Blog.objects.filter(user_id=user).aggregate(c=Count('id'))
    for i in range(numblog['c']):
        blogquery = Blog.objects.filter(user_id=user)[i]
        postquery = Post.objects.filter(blog_id=blogquery.pk)[:5]
    return render(request, "myapp/page.html", {'blogquery ':blogquery,'postquery ':postquery  })
```

expected result in template:

```
{% for b in blogquery %}
    {{ b.name }} ### here name of blog 
        {% for p in postquery %}
            {% if p.blog_id == b.pk %}
                {{ p.content }} ### here last 5 post of THAT blog
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT 2

In a view, if I print result it work but not render in template

```
@login_required
def page(request):
    user = request.user.id
    numblog = Blog.objects.filter(user_id=user).aggregate(c=Count('id'))
    for i in range(numblog['c']):
        blogquery = Blog.objects.filter(user_id=user)[i]
        postquery = Post.objects.filter(blog_id=blogquery.pk)[:5]
        for p in postquery:
            print (blogquery.pk, p.pk)
    return render(request, "myapp/page.html", {'blogquery ':blogquery,'postquery ':postquery  })
```

Comment: What are you intending to achieve here? Obviously that won't work.

Comment: I need to filter a family inside a for cycle and pass it in template...

Comment: But you need to think about your logic here. What is `family` after the for loop? Of course, it's the value of the *last* result. There is nothing to loop over in the template. **You need to explain exactly what you want to do**. Why do you need a loop at all?

Comment: edited post detailed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is surprising how you don't understand that repeatedly assigning to the same variable within a loop will just give you the *last* value.

But nevertheless, you don't need any of this code. You should just follow the relationship in the template.

```
@login_required
def page(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.filter(user=user).prefetch_related('post_set')
    return render(request, "myapp/page.html", {'blogs ': blogs })
```

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
    {{ blog.name }}
    {% for post in blog.post_set.all|slice:"5" %}
        {{ post.content }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

(You haven't shown your models so I presume the related_name from Blog to Post is called `post_set`, change as necessary.

Comment: Note that prefetch_related is an optimisation; the code would work exactly the same without it.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

That's not correct. You don't need to use for loop. If you need to get the last 5 rows you can do this i.e.:

```
def page(request):
    family= Author.objects.all().order_by('-pk')[:5]
    return render(request, "myapp/page.html", {'family':family})
```

another approach is to limit the results in your template:

```
{% for item in family %}
    {% if forloop.counter < 6 %}
       {{ item.pk }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I understand, but my situation in little bit complex... I need to filter a family passing for a for cycle. But it not render if I do this...

Comment: @JuConte explain a bit more so I can help you. What is your expected result?

Comment: @JuConte not usre if you understand how `Models` work. You do not need to use a for loop to a query. All the info you need to fetch can be fetch via the query if you construct it correctly.

Comment: I dont know how in this case :D

Comment: I try, but see my expected results in template... I need to render a blog in a row and inside the row of blog render last 5 post

Comment: @JuConte I can't get clearly what exactly you are trying to do. Maybe you need to use another template file and include it in an `iframe` in your basic template